# select from two tables using subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a database with two tables users and orders

```
users: user_id(primary), fname, lname, email, password, gender

orders: order_no(primary), user_id(foriegn), beans, type, extras, city
```

The orders table have only users who submitted orders.

I need to know how to select all users with the count of their orders if they have orders or don't.

#### Additional Info posted as an answer....

#### users table:

```
user_id fname lname email password gender
1        a     aa    aaa  123      m
2        b     bb    bbb  34       f
```

#### orders table:

```
order_no user_id bean type extras city
1         2       s    d    rr     ggg
2         2       s    d     rr     ggg
```

how to select all users table columns plus orders count for a and b so the new table will be:

```
user_id fname lname email password gender orders_count
1       a      aa    aaa   123      m      0
2       b      bb    bbb   34       f      2
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   select U.user_id,
          COUNT(O.user_id)
     from users U 
left join orders O on U.user_id=O.user_id
 group by U.user_id
```

Comment: Don't post tab delimited code - really screws with formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your update is basically requesting what [pcofre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533033/select-from-two-tables-using-subquery/5533065#5533065) already gives you. You just need to add the additional required columns to your `select` list and provide a column alias for the aggregate.

```
SELECT U.user_id,
       U.fname,
       U.lname,
       U.email,
       U.password,
       U.gender,
       COUNT(O.user_id) AS orders_count
FROM   users U
       LEFT JOIN orders O
         ON U.user_id = O.user_id
GROUP  BY U.user_id  /*<-- Don't need to add other users 
                          columns to GROUP BY in MySQL*/
```

Comment: yuck, relying on that [MySQL functionality](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html).  Valid, but not something I'd suggest for those learning SQL because the values in the non-grouped columns will be arbitrary.

Comment: @OMG- They are functionally dependent on `user_id`. There can only be one value per `group`

Comment: [Some discussion on this](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/debunking-group-by-myths.html)

Comment: So that's where Roland went to - good for him.  He used to  be on SO.  Yes, ANSI standard supports MySQL (and SQLite's) interpretation - but the other actual vendors don't.  You're looking at only this question, when people looking for their answer will have something different.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the updated information, use:

```
   SELECT u.*,
          COALESCE(x.orders_count, 0) AS orders_count
     FROM USERS u
LEFT JOIN (SELECT o.user_id, 
                  COUNT(*) AS orders_count
             FROM ORDERS o
         GROUP BY o.user_id) x ON x.user_id = u.user_id
 ORDER BY u.user_id
```